# Chrome crashes when js code executed

Tags: google-chrome

Every time this code is executed:

```
 $('.title').on("focus", function(event){
        if($(this).html() == "") {
         $(this).html("&nbsp;");
        }
     });
```

Chrome "Crashes" displaying the "Aw, Snap!", tried looking in chrome://crashes but the log never get logged there.

Any idea why it might do this?

**32.0.1664.3 dev**

Comment: Try $(this).html(" ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it worked in other versions of chrome this version seems bugged, i was able to solve it with using "click" instead of "focus".

Answer (score 2):

The simple reason why it is happening is: The on focus event keeps on triggering. And the if condition keeps on going on multiple times causing the chrome to crash.

try

```
if(!$(this).html().length) {
   $(this).html(" ");
}
```